# How do Bible scholars interpret the phraseology of Mark 10:21?

Tags: mark, love

In Mark 10, we read about the rich man who wanted to inherit eternal life. Jesus reminds him of the Commandments to which the man says that he has been following them since he was a boy. Verse 21 says that Jesus looked at the person and loved him. Now, love is an emotion that is static in nature. The better usage in the context, would be 'liked'. As it stands, Mark 10:21 uses 'loved'.

How do Bible scholars interpret the phraseology of Mark 10:21?

Comment: What basis do you have for suggesting that the sacred text is incorrect?  Why is it even surprising that Jesus would love someone?  What Greek word should have been used since there is nothing in Greek equivalent to the English "liked" in contradistinction to "loved"?

Comment: I think you need to substantiate that 1) love is an emotion, and 2) that it is static.

Comment: Thanks, Mike Borden. As per the rules of English Grammar, the verb ' love ' is not used in Continuous Tense. Thus, it is incorrect to say " I am / I was loving God " . In fact, Jesus loved the rich man, even before they would speak to each other. And, as per Christian values, you need to love a person even though you may not like everything about him .  Thus my suggestion that ' loved' is not the most appropriate translation in Mk 10:21.

Comment: Mike Borden, please see the write-up on maclaren.com . I admit that love is a secondary emotion comprising elements of the primary emotions. Love is an emotion in the sense that there is little role of intellect in building it up. It is static in the sense that passing emotions like hatred and fear are not meant to make a lasting effect on its intensity.

Answer (score 4):

Love, from a biblical perspective, can certainly have an emotional component, but it is not static. Love is ongoing and active, always looking out for the well being of its object.

The man in Mark 10 triggered an emotional response in Jesus that had a much deeper spiritual component. The man was evidently sincere, but his sincerity was based on a faulty understanding about how he could "inherit eternal life." Eternal life is not something a person inherits; rather, it is a gift from God that is based not on good works, such as obeying God's commandments, but on the unmerited, unearned favor of God. In one word, grace.

The man in search of eternal life had succeeded, perhaps, in keeping most of the commandments, but he had obviously failed to obey the very first commandment, which says,

> “You shall have no other gods before[or *besides*] me. (Exodus 20:3 NIV).

Jesus gave the man a choice: Either hold on to your wealth, or follow me. The man chose the former.

Remember, Jesus experienced a full panoply of emotions, many--if not most--of them more intense and more finely nuanced than the emotions of a mere mortal. Here are the main ones (look [here](https://www.crosswalk.com/faith/spiritual-life/10-real-life-emotions-jesus-expressed.html)):

- joy
- exhaustion
- anger
- disgust
- sorrow
- compassion
- -frustration
- agony
- empathy
- -forgiveness

What attitude and what emotions was Jesus experiencing as he interacted with the rich man in Mark 10? I suggest they were an admixture of compassion, empathy, and perhaps even a little sorrow.

In conclusion, Jesus experienced every temptation known to man, and the emotions that accompanied them, yet he never stumbled or deviated from the perfect plan His Father mapped out for Him in eternity past.

> For we do not have a high priest who is unable to empathize with our
> weaknesses, but we have one who has been tempted in every way, just as
> we are—yet he did not sin (Hebrews 4:15 NIV).

Oh, and does love sometimes involve liking another person? Personally, I have met a few people in my life whom I liked right away. If and when I continued to get to know them, however, sooner or later that liking would need to morph into something deeper and more meaningful, and that is the  forgiving and sacrificial kind of love the Bible calls ***agape***.

Answer (score 3):

The original Greek word:

From [The Blue Letter Bible](https://www.blueletterbible.org/nkjv/mar/10/13-31/t_conc_967021)

> Inflected: ἠγάπησεν
> Root:  ἀγαπάωSpeaker Icon
> Strong's:  G25
> English:   loved
> Code:  V-AAI-3S
> Long:  Verb - Aorist Active Indicative - 3rd Person Singular

Transliterated: agapaō

Word meanings are tricky in the best of situations.
The translator has the task of

1. understanding what the author meant and then
2. selecting a word that will communicate that meaning to the reader.

In this case agapaō does translate to "loved". The context of the passage and how the word is used in other places in scripture helps us understand what agapaō is intended to mean.
Here are some examples.

> Mat 5:43 “You have heard that it was said, ‘You shall love your neighbor and hate your enemy.’
> Mat 5:44 “But I say to you, love your enemies, bless those who curse you, do good to those who hate you, and
> pray for those who spitefully use you and persecute you,
>
> Mat 5:46 “For if you love those who love you, what reward have you? Do not even the tax collectors do the same?
>
> Mat 6:24 “No one can serve two masters; for either he will hate the one and love the other, or else he will be loyal to the one and despise the other. You cannot serve God and mammon.

In these examples love is not an emotion and it is not static. Love is how you treat someone else, it is action toward another person.

We have a clearer understanding of part 1 of the translator's task - understanding the original intent.
For part 2 of the task we have to select an English word that communicates the same thing as the original intent.

You offer the English word "liked" as an alternative to "loved". This would mean that "like" would fit in place of "love" in the scriptures listed:
But I say to you, "like" your enemies....
For if you "like" those who "like" you, what reward have you?.... etc.

The word "like" or "liked" falls short of the original intent.
The key is to understand what the Bible means by "loved" and avoid bringing your own bias about what love is or is not.

Answer (score 3):

The word used means, 'to love', and is ***agapao*.** It is not the other Greek words for love used in the New Testament, namely, *phileo* (to be a friend) or *philadelphos* (brotherly love), or *philandros* (love of mankind).

The words translated from apage are interesting in how different they are to what people today lump together under the one word, 'love'. Agape love is principled love, not a physical feeling, or a sexual urge. Nothing of the sort. Agape love is what God has for those whom he saves; they have done nothing to deserve his salvation; they do not love him the same way he loves them. Indeed, he loves them first before they begin to love him. As the apostle John explained,

> "...God is love *[agapao].* In this was manifested the love of God toward us,
> because that God sent his only begotten Son into the world, that we
> might live through him. Herein is love, not that we loved God, but
> that he loved us, and sent his Son to be the propitiation for our
> sins." I John 4:8-10 A.V.

The love that sent Christ into this sin-sick world was the same love Christ had for those he came to save. It was based in divine principle, but was not cold-blooded. It was warmer and more tender that we could ever imagine. That was the love Jesus had for that sincere young man who wanted to please God the Father by doing what was right. Two Bible commentaries I have make different points about this:

> "Mark alone has the little note that Jesus felt affection for the man
> (v. 21), further implying that the man was sincere. All this means
> that the only thing that stood between him and Jesus was the man's
> love for his possessions (v. 22)... 'Jesus looked at him and loved
> him': This detail is peculiar to the Markan form of the story and may
> be intended to make the man's refusal all the more tragic." *Mark*
> Larry W. Hurtado, pp.164 & 169, Hendrickson, 1983
>
> "The way Mark presents the story certainly gives us the impression
> that this man was both serious and sincere. This comes out in his own
> actions and words and possibly also in the fact that Mark says Jesus
> loved him, suggesting perhaps that although not yet in the kingdom of
> God, he saw how earnestly he desired eternal life... That Jesus is
> here said to have looked at him and loved him is a strong reminder of
> the amazing fact that we are the objects of God's love even when we
> are least aware of the depth of our need." Mark Geoffrey Grogan,
> p.186, Christian Focus, 1995

Christ's affection for this young man was more than merely liking him. Even we can like people without having any actual love for them, but because the word for the highest form of principled, divine love is used in this verse, we may be sure that Jesus was moved within himself at how earnest this young man was.

Comment: Your explanation to the use of agape in this verse is enlightening. But I am puzzling. When agape is a principle love, it is unconditional and no need to be said explicitly. Why would Mark write Jesus loved him when He heard his reply? Furthermore, Jesus surely knew he just worked by the law, not by his heart and for God. How to explain agape being used in this circumstance? I doubt the young man is looking for rewards from Jesus rather than earnest to serve God.

Comment: @Vincent Wong   I refer you to my 4th paragraph. On Earth, only Jesus can read hearts and minds so I cannot respond further, other than to say that the Holy Spirit inspired Mark to write down that one point none of the others recorded.

Answer (score 1):

In Mark 10:21, the use of 'agape' is proper to express the love of God to human (as Anne's answer already explained). A deeper understanding is why Mark had it written.

The rich man who claimed *'he had kept the commandments since I was a boy' (Mark 10:20)* was certainly a person abided by the law. The law has no teaching of 'eternal life', so it is notable when he asked Jesus "what must I do to inherit eternal life?" (Mark 10:17 NIV). It implies the rich man found abided by the law is not sufficient, that urged him to find a new way of salvation.

If the rich man satisfied Jesus' expectation, the likely Jesus' expression should be 'rejoice' (as used in Luke 10:21) rather than 'love'. Let's review further from the origin of 'eternal life'.

The earliest reference of 'eternal life' appears in John 3:15-16, when Jesus taught Nicodemus in His early ministry.

> 15 that everyone who believes may have **eternal life** in him.”
>
> 16 For God so loved the world that he gave his one and only Son, that whoever believes in him shall not perish but have **eternal life**.

Jesus further claimed 'He is the light'. *'Whoever lives by the truth comes into the light, so that it may be seen plainly that what they have done **has been done in the sight of God**' (John 3:21 NIV)*

Now it can be seen the instruction of Jesus is customised for the rich man. Jesus began with "One thing you lack ......" (Mark 10:21)

Jesus loved the rich man, for he was just a step away from eternal life. For God so loved the world that God does not want to condemn the world, but to save the world through His Son. **Jesus' love also reveal His sadness**, when He heard the reply from the rich man saying *"Teacher, all these I have kept since I was a boy" (Mark 10:20 NIV)*. As it was told in John 3:21, what he had done should be done in the sight of God, but he did only explicitly by the law, his wealth was kept from the poor that is the opposite.

Mark seems to have kept more Jesus' emotional expression. Earlier in Mark 10:14, Jesus was **indignant** to His disciples not to allow the little children get close to Him. This emotional expression was not found in Matthew and Luke.

Answer (score 0):

The verse is correct, Jesus loved him because the man in subject had obeyed the commandments of God since his youth and Jesus said
**If you love me, keep my commandments**
So there is a connection between being loved by God and keeping his commandments.